# Azure Kubernetes - RBAC role for namespace isolation

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, rbac

i would like to know if is possible to isolate namespace on Azure Kubernetes service. Now if i give rbac role to my colleague they can see all namespace, i would like to segregate namespace for department, e.g. data can see only data namespace, dev can see only den namespace etc..

is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes, You have to Enable `AKS-managed Azure Active Directory`, `Role-based access control (RBAC)` & [Azure RBAC for Kubernetes Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-ad-rbac?toc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Faks%2Ftoc.json&bc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json#create-the-aks-cluster-resources-for-app-devs). There are 2 options:

```
az aks create \
  -g myResourceGroup \
  -n myManagedCluster \
  --enable-aad \
  --enable-azure-rbac
```

1st Option:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: data
  labels:
    kubernetes.io/metadata.name: data
---
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: data-view-access
  namespace: data
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: view
subjects:
- kind: Group
  namespace: data
  name: <GROUP_OBJECT_ID>
```

2nd Option is to use Azure Custom Roles as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/manage-azure-rbac#create-role-assignments-for-users-to-access-cluster) and also with this example from user yk1 :

```
az role assignment create \
  --role "Azure Kubernetes Service RBAC Reader" \
  --assignee <AAD-ENTITY-ID> \
  --scope $AKS_ID/namespaces/<namespace-name>
```

NOTE: All users must be member of `Azure Kubernetes Service Cluster User Role` in order the execute `az aks get-credentials`

Comment: you can put this example in there `az role assignment create --role "Azure Kubernetes Service RBAC Reader" --assignee <AAD-ENTITY-ID> --scope $AKS_ID/namespaces/<namespace-name>`

Comment: thanks a lot, i added your example!

Comment: Hi all, sorry for the delay. Thanks for the example. With that command i can segregate the namespace, so if i create some azure ad group for all namespace eg: rbac_namespace1 rbac_namespace2 ecc... i can set with that command the group to relative namespace? Which role i have to give to manage all aspect of namespace?

Comment: For all Namespaces the user needs `Azure Kubernetes Service Cluster User Role` & `Azure Kubernetes Service RBAC Reader`  or if you are using Option1: you can use a `ClusterRoleBinding` instead of `RoleBinding`  for the ClusterRole `view`. Could you please markt the answer as correct to help other users with the same question?

Comment: Thanks Phil, i prefer to manage via rbac i think. So after that, can i remove user from this role Azure Kubernetes Service Cluster Admin Role, Azure Kubernetes Service Cluster User Role, 
Azure Kubernetes Service Contributor Role ? Now we have to put user in all of that role becouse without it, now user can do nothing. I will test today an i will let you now

Comment: the role `Azure Kubernetes Service Cluster User Role` the user will need in order to run a `az aks get-credentials`. the other roles you can remove. Could you please mark the answer as correct to help other users with the same question?

Comment: Hi @PhilipWelz , added rbac role to my aks without success. I executed:  "az role assignment create --role "Azure Kubernetes Service RBAC Admin" --assignee myazureadgroup --scope /subscriptions/mysub/resourcegroups/myrg/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/myaks/namespaces/mynamespace" and "az role assignment create --role "Azure Kubernetes Service RBAC Reader" --assignee myazureadgroup --scope /subscriptions/mysub/resourcegroups/myrg/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/myaks/namespaces/mynamespace"
but i got message "error from server forbidden". What i miss?

Comment: Hi, i solved my problem with first option described by Philip

Comment: As integration i created custom role inside aks and created role bindings with namespace to segregate it

Comment: I followed steps for Option 2 above, when I run a kubectl command like "kubectl get ns", I get this message: "To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code ABCDEFG to authenticate". Once I enter the code, I get error browser: "Your sign-in was successful but your admin requires the device requesting access to be managed by to access this resource."

This may just be our company security policy but I wonder why it has kicked in? If I use my full admin (owner of AKS) account, I have no issue doing the kubectl.